# Consulta muestra números que no existen

Tags: java, sql-server

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con java Swing, pero pasa que la consulta me devuelve números que no hay.

En la siguiente imagen, muestro los números que devuelve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la siguiente imagen muestra los que hay en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto se me hace raro ya que en ambos casos es la misma consulta, la consulta la tengo en un procedimiento almacenado.

Esta es la consulta del procedimiento:

```
SELECT k.Folio, (CASE WHEN k.Folio_Interno = 0 THEN '' ELSE k.Folio_Interno END) AS Folio_Interno, c.Descripcion_Corta AS Movimiento, SUM(k.Cantidad) AS Cantidad,
   FORMAT(k.FMovimiento, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS FMovimiento
FROM Kardex AS k
INNER JOIN Conceptos AS c ON c.Id_Concepto = k.Id_Concepto
INNER JOIN Materiales AS m ON m.Clave_Material = k.Clave_Material
WHERE (c.Cuenta IN (1, 10)) AND k.Estatus <> 'C' AND (CONVERT(DATE, k.FMovimiento) 
BETWEEN '20/11/2023' AND '22/11/2023')
GROUP BY k.Folio, k.Folio_Interno, c.Descripcion_Corta, k.FMovimiento
ORDER BY k.Folio
```

Y este el código que me retorna la consulta:

```
public ArrayList<kardexA2_DAO> getByCuenta(kardexA2_DAO kardex)
{
    ArrayList<kardexA2_DAO> movimientos = new ArrayList<>();
    
    try
    {
        cs = cpmAlmacen.prepareCall("{Call stp_Kardex_getByCuenta (?, ?, ?, ?)}");
        
        cs.setInt(1, kardex.getCuenta1());
        cs.setInt(2, kardex.getCuenta2());
        cs.setObject(3, kardex.getFecha1());
        cs.setObject(4, kardex.getFecha2());
        
        rs = cs.executeQuery();
        
        while(rs.next())
        {
            kardexA2_DAO obj = new kardexA2_DAO();
            obj.setFolio(rs.getShort("Folio"));
            obj.setFolio_Interno(rs.getInt("Folio_Interno"));
            obj.setMovimiento(rs.getString("Movimiento"));
            obj.setCantidad(rs.getDouble("Cantidad"));
            obj.setFMovimiento(rs.getObject("FMovimiento"));
            movimientos.add(obj);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        Conexion.cerrarPrep(cs);
    }
    
    return movimientos;
}
```

Comment: Si los números no existen ¿Estás seguro que están consultando a la misma base de datos?

Comment: Si, de hecho los demás datos que me trae de vuelta si son los correctos, solo estos números que muestro en la primera imagen, son los que no coinciden

Comment: Lo que has compartido no ayuda a solucionar el problema. Revisa que los valores que envías sean los mismos. No te podemos ayudar a debuggear un problema sin tener acceso a tu entorno.